# Difficulty in understanding c++ string literals

Tags: c++, string

Here the below code is my some part of my program. It doesn't execute it says c++ forbids converting string constants to char*.How can I fix this error?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bank
{
private:
    char name[20];
    int acc;
    float amount;

public:
    Bank()
    {
        strcpy("",name);
        acc = 0;
        amount = 0;
    }

    void open(int a)
    {
        cout << "Enter name:";
        cin >> name;
        acc = a;
        cout << "Enter Amount" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
    }

    void edit(int flag, float a);
};

int main()
{
    Bank B[10];
}
```

Comment: You have the arguments wrong for [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). And unless it's part of your exercise or assignment, please don't use `char` arrays for your string, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: `strcpy(x, y);` is like `x = y;`.  The destination is the first parameter, the source is the second parameter.  That's a fairly typical pattern in the standard C library, and often adopted as the often typical pattern in the standard C++ library as well.  Caveat: there are some standard APIs that differ, and some platform SDKs that follow a different convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::strcpy("", name);` needs to be `std::strcpy(name, "");`

Although, setting aside the fact that `std::string` would be a *far better* type for `name` (the future King of England, Charles Mountbatten-Windsor, would not be able to be a customer), writing

```
name[0] = 0;
```

would be sufficient.

Comment: Or, for the (overly?) pedantic (namely, me), `name[0] = '\0';`. Which does exactly the same thing. <g> +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker: (Not for your benefit as I know you know this), but the only difference between `'\0'` and `0` is that the former is a `char` type, whereas `0` is an octal literal of type `int`. In C they are both `int` types. Personally I don't like the `'\0'` notation in case someone removes the backslash.